# Why aren't all the Buttons being displayed correctly in a Container?

Tags: java, swing, awt

So I am learning Java with the *IntelliJ* software and am trying to learn how to add multiple `ActionListeners` to the program.
I am using a video from the **Programming Guru** on Youtube to learn this.
I have followed his steps up until I got to the point where he adds the `ActionListeners`.
However, at this point, there is only a single Button being displayed in the wrong location.

Here is the code I have:

```java
import javax.swing.*
import java.awt.*

class MultipleButtonsEvent {
    public MultipleButtonsEvent(){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setbounds(0, 0, 500, 500);
        Container container = frame.getContentPane();

        container.setLayout(null);

        JButton btn1 = new JButton("Button 1");
        btn1.setBounds(150, 10, 200, 40);
        container.add(btn1);

        JButton btn2 = new JButton("Button 1");
        btn1.setBounds(150, 60, 200, 40);
        container.add(btn2);

        JButton btn3 = new JButton("Button 1");
        btn1.setBounds(150, 110, 200, 40);
        container.add(btn3);

        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MultipleButtonsEvent mbe = new MultipleButtonsEvent();
    }
}
```

All I am getting at this time is the correct screen size, however only 'Button 1' is displayed with the wrong dimensions and it is nearly positioned just above the centre of the panel.
Additionally, when I remove the following line:

```java
container.add(btn1);
```

it gives me a blank screen panel.

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You are repeating the call to `btn1.setBounds` three times. I assume your are supposed to set bounds for `btn2` and `btn3`?

Comment: @MartinSieburg *that solved it. * - a better solution is to NOT use a null layout and instead use layout managers. Then the layout manager is responsible for setting the size/location of the buttons. Its easier to maintain and Swing was designed to be used with layout managers.